# Need help for PSD To WordPress using Thesis framework

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm experienced developer and know very well how to convert PSD To HTML/WP. I have been using Woo Canvas framework to convert PSD to WP. But Now, I need help how to properly convert PSD to WordPress using Thesis framework.

Thesis framework is bit different since it uses "Skins", "Boxes" and etc to customize a site. I want few things to confirm from people how know Thesis framework.

Here is the png version of PSD file
http://screencast.com/t/JujlDjZm1Jwr
You can see, it has top header menu, header image, slider, menu, posts and sidebars.

Now my questions are:

- How to properly perform customization without disturbing core framework files?
- Should I be working on Skins, child theme and boxes?
- Would I need to add some custom template integration?
- I think, Thesis framework doesn't provide slider feature so I guess, I would need to add custom markup to add the home page slider?
- How to create separate sidebar and that should be customizable?

I can see there are several options that I can set but it is not fulfilling the whole requirement.

I can go directly adding divs for each section and registering wp_nav but I first wanted to hear from some Thesis framework experts. I would be very thankful for any of your help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the date of this post I am assuming you are using Thesis 2.1x. This version of thesis does not require you to do any programming to accomplish any of the tasks that you asked about above. You can use the Custom CSS Tab on the Thesis Admin Page to add your custom CSS. You can also use the CSS editor to add CSS and create variables (Thesis is SASS ready).

To add a slider just use an HTML Container and add your slider to either a widget or Feature Box.

You can add Javascript to specific templates by clicking the gear icon next to the Template Button in the HTML editor.

If you really want to use your own code you can add skin specific php to your wp-content/thesis/custom.php file (same as wp functions.php) and you can use master.php to add code to every site on your network (wp-content/thesis/master.php). And of course you can enqueue and register scripts that you create in either of these files, as well.

I usually create a custom folder and keep all my function/js/class files in there and then just include of require them using the THESIS_USER_SKIN_URL constant. This constant enables  Thesis to find your file within a specific skin.

The Thesis Forums are probably the best place to find Thesis answers. They have a great community.